# Rects from getClientRects() are empty when JSON.stringified on iOS8 but it works well on iOS7

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

In my iOS app I have an UIWebView that loads some html content. The user can select text and create highlight over selection. I need coordinates of highlighted area so I am using getClientRects() in the following javascript function:

```
function rectsForSelection() {
    var i = 0, j = 0;
    var allSelections = window.getSelection();

    var result = []; // An empty array right now
    // Generally, there is only one selection, but the spec allows multiple
    for (i=0; i < allSelections.rangeCount; i++) {
        var aRange = allSelections.getRangeAt(i);
        var rects = aRange.getClientRects();
        for (j=0; j<rects.length; j++) {
            result.push(rects[j]);
        }
    }
    return JSON.stringify(result); 
}
```

On device with iOS7 I get the correct JSON string representing the rects array that looks like this:

```
[{\"left\":454,\"right\":585,\"top\":126,\"height\":16,\"bottom\":142,\"width\":131}, {\"left\":312,\"right\":515,\"top\":142,\"height\":16,\"bottom\":158,\"width\":203}]
```

However, on iOS8 I get empty content for every rect in array (the number of rects in array on iOS8 is correct though):

```
[{},{}]
```

I have read about some issues about JSON.stringify function on iOS8 but couldn't find any reasonable explanation about what causes that problem. Can I use some alternative method that converts an array of rects to JSON or some similar format string? I would really like to avoid manually converting to string every rectangle and keep on using only javascript if possible...